# can we configure test cases fields in TestLink?

Tags: manual-testing, testlink

I am using a specific template of test cases in excel file. We don't want to leave that format and want a tool where we can import/export our test cases. now after some R&D we are considering TestLink, As i have not worked with TestLink i am wondering, Can we Add/Remove/Modify fields used for test cases in TestLink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login as Admin
2. In left side, there is a section named "System"

[image]

3. Under System you will find a option "Define Custom Fields"

using this option you can create custom fields

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You cant add customs fields . 
If you really need it you have to request it from the testlink developer tesm.
But i think that is also not possible.

Comment: I have performed some more R&D and found we can add custom fields. Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: can you please share your findings.

Comment: Answered my question